# error in imports of import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

Tags: android

Hello i want to run [this](http://oudomvilla.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/tutorial-1-transparent-panel-linear-layout-on-mapview-google-map/) tutorial but i getting error on importing

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
```

Although i have updated  available packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Have you changed your build target to use the Google API form of your API level?](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/mapactivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-type.html)

Answer (score 0):

for error "import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;"
Please Include this jar (below given link)
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgooglemapsapi11jar.htm