# Error in import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, dependencies

I'm creating a simple app to test the `place picker` Google API. I'm following [this](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-google-maps-android) tutorials. I'm stuck in import the following libraries.

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

In above import the `maps` is highlighted and when I move cursor on it, it says `Cannot resolve symbol maps`.

I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565366/error-in-imports-of-import-com-google-android-maps-mapactivity), but the answer of this describes the method to be followed in eclipse, I'm using Android studio.

My `manifest.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kaushal28.googlemaps">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<application


    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <mata-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBWgvR6uCf6EZLjf0IjYkx9mTQZDA8wy2g "/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And my Build.Gradle(Module App) is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kaushal28.googlemaps"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
//    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}
```

I'm new to android. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Google Play service version, that fixed my issue.

Comment: how to check exactly?

Comment: and what if it is outdated? what changes I've to make?

Answer (score 0):

You are following a tutorial covering Google Maps API v1 which is deprecated. You must use [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/).

Comment: Is there any exact tutorial for v2? because in the link which you mentioned it is given a code snippet to implement `place picker` and I don;t know how to use this code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For me, this is the best reference with examples (see the menu on the left): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: before following the mentioned tutorial, I was following this, but can't understand how to implement `place picker` on my map

Comment: see above link. It contains 2 code snippets for place picker but i don't know where to place it

Comment: The documentation I have linked is about Google Maps API v2. Place Picker is on Google Places API for Android. The documentation that you have linked has nothing to do with Place Picker...

Comment: I.m sorry I mentioned the wrong link it is:https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Comment: Yes, that's the Google Places API for Android, but it's a different API for different purposes. To show a map on an Android app you need Google Maps API v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: But I'm creating this app , which shows the information of tapped place.

Comment: for this I've to create a map activity or empty activity?

Comment: You need to create a `MapActivity`